# Database design for getting best matching documents in Nosql database

Tags: python, mongodb, couchdb, nosql

In our project we have to develop a module which search for most related document available in our database. The search criteria is by using minimum three keyword (three keyword for matching accuracy).We are extract keyword manually and automatically by using keyword extraction modules. So we are not completely sure how we have to design the database and we are are confused about database selection also, most probably it will be Mongodb. So any have any suggestion or know about any article or document available in internet about these type of database design or application, sharing those will be very helpful....

Comment: Please elaborate. How many fields will there be to be searched? Could you give us an example of the records to be saved? Please comment if you did so.

Comment: it's like , suppose there is a article related to chess, actually it's about chess strategy, so the main category will be 'chess' and sub category will be 'chess strategy', so while searching it will show all the article related to chess strategy. The category will be tree like structure, main category(chess) > sub category(chess strategy) > sub of sub category(type of chess strategy) etc some times the category levels will be up to 10 steps. All this category creation done by application automatically by some predefined templates. so searching should go up to bottom level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [more-like-this query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html) in [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org).